# One source is much slower than the other side when join history data in Flink

Tags: join, apache-kafka, stream, hdfs, apache-flink

When consuming history data in join operator with eventTime, reading data from one source is much slower than the other. As a result, the join operator will cache much data from the faster source in order to wait the slower source.

The question is that how can I make the difference of consumers' speed small?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "...make the difference of consumers' speed small". If you want to avoid caching a lot of data, and you can't control the source speed, then I think your only option is to use a smaller window, so that less data is cached. See [Window Join](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/joining.html#window-join) for more details on this.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have found the answer from other place. The url is http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/One-source-is-much-slower-than-the-other-side-when-join-history-data-td26365.html